# Joomla 3.7.1 - Adding Links and title tags to article intro images

Tags: php, html, joomla

Hi guys wondering how I can manually add a link from Joomla intro article images to their corresponding article and also add a title tag to the link.

Ideally the way I want to do this is to for example wrap an achor tag around the image reference in the blog-item.php file (also want to achieve this for generic articles). And then within the anchor tag capture the related image alt tag and populate the title tag with that value.

Below is where I'm at. It's not currently working, not sure why as it should be pretty straight forward. I'm not a php developer, wondering what i'm missing.

Also already cleared both browser and joomla caches after my changes.

Any help would be appreciated, cheers guys

```
                <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid)); ?>" title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>">
            <img

                src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>"
                alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>"/>
            </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code work, add just before your code.

```
<?php $images = json_decode($this->item->images); ?>
```

and your code will start working.

Already tested and it worked.

Comment: Hi Mash thanks for this but I'm still not seeing the article info function as a link. So far I've found three locations in the template override directory that this is occuring but thats not to say there isnt more. This relates to creating default,featured and blog articles. 

Once i make the change i clear both the joomla and browser caches and refresh the page. Is there anything else i could be missing?

Comment: Hi, Maybe i am not understanding you properly. the code above will allow you to use the variable $images.

Now if you want to put a link manually, you can use the caption field of intro image

`<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_caption); ?`

Comment: Hi Mash, I just want the intro image to link to the related article. I don't really want the image to have a caption attached to it. A simple alt value for the image and title tag containing the same value is what I am aiming to achieve :)

Comment: Hi Nick then the code below should work just fine

`<?php $images = json_decode($this->item->images); ?>
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid)); ?>" title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>">
            <img

                src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>"
                alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>"/>
            </a>`